# Probability of meeting confusion in the results

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the following problem

Maria Victoria and Carlos agreed to meet downtown between 12 noon and 1 PM. They both get there at any moment in that time interval. Assuming their arrival times to be independent, find:

The probability that Carlos and Maria Victoria will meet if Maria Victoria
waits 5 minutes but Carlos waits 20.

The sample space is $\Omega=\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}: 0 \leq x \leq 60, 0 \leq y \leq 60\}$

from where

$x:$Maria Victoria's arrival time and $y:$ Carlos arrival time. My first question is, how would this event look described as a set?

Consider the image (sorry for the improvised image)

[image]

First find the area of the $T1$ triangle, which is

$$\frac{40 \cdot 40}{2}$$

And the area for $T2$

$$\frac{55 \cdot 55}{2}$$

And the area of the sample space $60 \cdot 60$, So the probability that they will not meet is

$$\frac{\frac{40 \cdot 40}{2} + \frac{55 \cdot 55}{2}}{60 \cdot 60}=\frac{185}{288}$$

And if I take the complement $1-\frac{185}{288}=\frac{103}{288}$

I only have the question of how is the representation as a set of the event

Comment: Goodness gracious ! Check your arithmetic !

Comment: @trueblueanil You're right, how inattentive I was. I am only left with the doubt of the representation of the event as a set.